# Cuál es la mejor manera para visualizar los datos de una lista obtenidos de mi controlador en un <p:datatable> o un <p:datalist>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo una lista de objetos que visualizo en mi vista con primefaces.

```
public void muestraValores(){
    for(Persona person: listaPersona){
        Persona p = null;
        int valor = person.getIdValor();
        String nombre = person.getNombre();
        String password = person.getPassword();
        p = new Persona(valor, nombre, password);
        lista.add(p);
    }
}
```

O también lo hago de esta manera!

```
public void muestraValores(){
    setLista(listaPersona);
}
```

Me gustaría que me dijeran cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo o cuál serían sus diferencias. Pero no se cuál es la diferencia en sí porque siempre he iterado sobre la lista para poder obtener los valores deseados

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo tu pregunta. El framework es quien itera por vos la lista. Vos solo debés pasarle la lista desde tu backing bean y el componente (sea de jsf o de alguna librería como Primefaces) se encarga por vos de como dibujar la tabla.

Algo como esto:

```
    <p:dataTable var="persona" value="#{miBackingBean.personas}">
        <p:column headerText="Nombre">
            <h:outputText value="#{persona.nombre}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Y tu Backing Bean algo así:

```
    @ManagedBean(name="miBackingBean")
    public class MiBackingBean implements Serializable {

        private List<Persona> personas;

        public void getPersonas() {
            return personas;
        }
    }
```

La **datable** o el **datalist** invocará al método **getPersonas()** de tu Backing Bean para obtener los valores a mostrar.

Comment: Entiendo esa parte. Solo que lo que hago para poder mostrar la lista en mi vista "xhtml" la itero en mi metodo "muestraValores()" en si la recorro pero un compañero a parte de que tiene sus metodos get y set en ese mismo metodo el  en vez de iterarlo como yo, el le setea la lista que va a devolver. Cabe mencionar que todo esto viene a partir de BD. Mira algo así lo  hace:

Comment: Es que yo para mostrar los valores itero sobre el resultado que me devuelve mi consulta a partir de mi PersonaDAOImpl, por eso tengo mi método de 'muestraValores()' y el solo setea el valor y ya no itera porque dice que viene a partir de mi PersonaDAOImpl, ya no es necesario iterar. Pero la duda que tengo es que no se si lo hago de esta manera sea mejor, sea mas viable, no se cual sea lo mejor manera de hacerlo, en esencia esa es mi duda? Gracias

Comment: Donde te confundes es cuando dices **Itero en mi método "muestraValores()** . Eso no es necesario, de hecho, solo estas creando una lista nueva con los mismos datos que tu lista original y que no es usada por nadie. Tu debes devolver la lista y el componente (en este caso un Datatable de Primefaces) tiene la lógica necesaria para, al momento de generar el html, iterar tu lista y formar la tabla que luego ves en pantalla.